# Samsung KNOX compatible apps

Tags: android, samsung-knox

Does anyone know how to build a test app that plays well with Samsung Knox? What do I have to so differently to build an app for samsung devices that have Knox installed on them?

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to be able to write an application and use Knox to provide authenticity assurance to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to take a look through here https://www.samsungknox.com/en/blog/what-app-wrapping and here https://www.samsungknox.com/en/resources.

Looks like you have to develop the app and then send it in to Samsung to have them 'wrap' it.

Answer (score 2):

From KNOX 2.0, App wrapping is not required.

This is from the Samsung KNOX 2.0 whitepaper:

The KNOX 2.0 platform features major enhancements to the Application Container from the original KNOX platform. **The most significant enhancement is the elimination of application wrapping. This is achieved by leveraging technology introduced by Google in Android 4.2 to support multiple users on tablet devices.** This enables enterprises to easily deploy custom applications without requiring Samsung to wrap the applications. It also reduces the barrier to entry for independent software developers wishing to develop applications for the KNOX container.

Complete White paper can be found here: http://www.samsung.com/ca/business-images/resource/white-paper/2014/03/Samsung_KNOX_tech_whitepaper_Final_140220-0.pdf

Multiple user: (Complete Ref: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers)
Android now allows multiple user spaces on shareable devices such as tablets. Each user on a device has his or her own set of accounts, apps, system settings, files, and any other user-associated data.

**As an app developer, there’s nothing different you need to do in order for your app to work properly with multiple users on a single device.** Regardless of how many users may exist on a device, the data your app saves for a given user is kept separate from the data your app saves for other users. The system keeps track of which user data belongs to the user process in which your app is running and provides your app access to only that user’s data and does not allow access to other users’ data.

Comment: I submited a request for developer status with KNOX. They asked me a bunch of questions about my app, and I never heard back from them. Any advice on how to submit apps for knox compatibility?

Comment: Again from the samsung site: "No need to change your app's source code or use an SDK to run in KNOX containers". 

I have personally not submitted a request. But I think you need to submit a request and wait for Samsung to get back. At which point you will have to submit your app, Samsung will do a testing of the app and makes it available in the KNOX app catalog if the application passes the Samsung's testing.

Comment: This is correct. KNOX does not need developers to change anything about their source. Containers will let you run the application just like a normal user. Source: I work for the Samsung KNOX project.